# Deployment Topology and Data center

Tags: deployment, database-connection, cluster-computing

I am trying to learn deployment topology and data centre topology for complex application. I know that answer to this question may vary depending on different scenarios. But I am talking about most probable and general case.

I browsed over the internet and came to know that complex large scale e-commerce J2EE applications are deployed on multiple application servers (e.g. weblogic cluster) and these weblogic application servers are connected to multiple data centres (where customer/application specific data is stored). I would like to know how these servers talk to multiple data centres (in terms of JDBC Connection and data source).

Also if there are multiple data centres then there is possibility of inconsistent data.

My knowledge about data centre is zero and would like to know more about how communication between application server and data centres takes place. In short I want to know typical production deployment topology along with data centers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex and broad question that is open to interpretation. You might want to start with something like this to get enough information to ask more specific questions that are a better fit for Stack Overflow: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077094/soa/construct-java-applications-through-distributed-object-technology.html

Comment: Link you shared is for distributed objects. I am not looking for that. I read that there will be multiple data centers and data will be replicated to other data centers through some techniques. Also about how servers connected to data centers. Its not about objects. Its about persisted data.

Comment: In Java data is almost always represented and transmitted in the form of objects. It is commonly persisted as objects as well. Data centers are comprised mostly of servers. The internet is full of useful information that should help you get a grasp on the fundamentals.